# Upload User ID to Database using Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

The thing is i a have a page where my user post shows and on the post there is a connect button in form of `form input`. Each of the post has the posters `id`. I want it such that when a user clicks on the connect button the poster's id is `INSERTED` into the database.

**The PHP**

```
<?php

$sql = <<<EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM programs;
EOF;

$ret = $db->querySingle($sql);

if ($ret == 0)
{
echo "<div class='no_prog'>No programs currently advertised</div>";
}
else
{
$rsql = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM programs ORDER BY id DESC;
EOF;


$rret = $db->query($rsql);

while ($rrow = $rret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $banner = $rrow['banner'];
    $banner_2 = $rrow['banner_2'];
    $title = $rrow['sem_title'];
    $spons = $rrow['sem_spons'];
    $link = $rrow['sem_link'];
    $company = $rrow['sem_comp'];
    $brief = $rrow['sem_brief'];
    $ad_id = $rrow['userid'];

    $usql = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = '$ad_id';
EOF;
    $uret = $db->query($usql);

    while ($urow = $uret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $ad_img = $urow['image'];
        $ad_name = $urow['fname'];


    echo "<div class=\"preview_prog\">
        <div class='posted_by'>
        <p><img src='$ad_img'></p>
</div>
<div class='ad_user_info'>
<div class='ad_info'>
    <div class='ad_info_img'>
        <img src='$ad_img'>
    </div>
    <div class='ad_info_name'>
    <p>$ad_name</p>
</div>
    <div class='ad_info_conn'>
    <div class='ad_info_conn_btn'>
        <div class='conn_img'>
            <img src='images/connect.png'>
        </div>

    //TOP INSERT $ad_id TO DATABASE

        <form action='connect_exec.php' method='post' id='connect_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='submit' name='connect' class='conn_text' id='connect' value='connect +'>
        <!--<a href='user_connect.php?userid=$ad_id' class='conn_text' name='user_connect'>Connect +</a>-->
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have tried putting the `form="action"` in an external `php` file but its not getting the`$ad_id`. Most likely because it not a link

**Action PHP**

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['connect']))
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
$ad_id = (int)$_GET['userid'];
$rand_num = rand();

$hsql =<<<EOF
SELECT COUNT(hash) as count FROM connect WHERE (user_one = '$my_id' AND user_two = '$ad_id') OR (user_one = '$ad_id' AND user_two = '$my_id');
EOF;

$hret = $db->querySingle($hsql);

if ($hret == 1)
{
    $response = "Your are already connected to '$ad_id'";
}
else
{
    $csql =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO connect (user_one, user_two, hash) VALUES ('$my_id', '$ad_id', '$rand_num');
EOF;
    $cret = $db->exec($csql);

    if (!$cret)
    {
        $message = "Error connecting to '$ad_id'";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Successfully Connected to '$ad_id'";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Please any advice on how i can upload the `$ad_id` to the database.

**Note that am new to PHP and know little Ajax**

Comment: where's your ajax?

Comment: try to add an hidden field within the form that you are creating in string with name "userid" which will have the id in its value that you want to receive in your action.php with `$_GET['userid']` in replace this `$_GET['userid']` with `$_POST['userid']`. You will get the userid

Comment: Splendid @SandeepGarg never thought of that. Very efficient way of achieving the aim. Thank you very much

Comment: I am posting answer below. Please upvote and mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: SO users. The question was down voted because i didn't add my `ajax` when clearly my problem wasn't from `ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add an hidden field within the form that you are creating in string with name "userid" which will have the id in its value that you want to receive in your action.php with `$_GET['userid']` in replace this `$_GET['userid']` with `$_POST['userid']`. You will get the userid

```
<?php

$sql = <<<EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM programs;
EOF;

$ret = $db->querySingle($sql);

if ($ret == 0)
{
echo "<div class='no_prog'>No programs currently advertised</div>";
}
else
{
$rsql = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM programs ORDER BY id DESC;
EOF;


$rret = $db->query($rsql);

while ($rrow = $rret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $banner = $rrow['banner'];
    $banner_2 = $rrow['banner_2'];
    $title = $rrow['sem_title'];
    $spons = $rrow['sem_spons'];
    $link = $rrow['sem_link'];
    $company = $rrow['sem_comp'];
    $brief = $rrow['sem_brief'];
    $ad_id = $rrow['userid'];

    $usql = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = '$ad_id';
EOF;
    $uret = $db->query($usql);

    while ($urow = $uret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $ad_img = $urow['image'];
        $ad_name = $urow['fname'];


    echo "<div class=\"preview_prog\">
        <div class='posted_by'>
        <p><img src='$ad_img'></p>
</div>
<div class='ad_user_info'>
<div class='ad_info'>
    <div class='ad_info_img'>
        <img src='$ad_img'>
    </div>
    <div class='ad_info_name'>
    <p>$ad_name</p>
</div>
    <div class='ad_info_conn'>
    <div class='ad_info_conn_btn'>
        <div class='conn_img'>
            <img src='images/connect.png'>
        </div>

    //TOP INSERT $ad_id TO DATABASE

        <form action='connect_exec.php' method='post' id='connect_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='hidden' name='userid' value='$ad_id'/>
        <input type='submit' name='connect' class='conn_text' id='connect' value='connect +'>
        <!--<a href='user_connect.php?userid=$ad_id' class='conn_text' name='user_connect'>Connect +</a>-->
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Action.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['connect']))
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
$ad_id = (int)$_POST['userid'];
$rand_num = rand();

$hsql =<<<EOF
SELECT COUNT(hash) as count FROM connect WHERE (user_one = '$my_id' AND user_two = '$ad_id') OR (user_one = '$ad_id' AND user_two = '$my_id');
EOF;

$hret = $db->querySingle($hsql);

if ($hret == 1)
{
    $response = "Your are already connected to '$ad_id'";
}
else
{
    $csql =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO connect (user_one, user_two, hash) VALUES ('$my_id', '$ad_id', '$rand_num');
EOF;
    $cret = $db->exec($csql);

    if (!$cret)
    {
        $message = "Error connecting to '$ad_id'";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Successfully Connected to '$ad_id'";
    }
}
}
?>
```